# App Store won't update

Tags: applications, mac-appstore

I'm trying to update Airmail to the latest version on my MacBook with El-Capitan 10.11.6 (15G31).

When I go under App Store > Updates, I see no new updates. When I search for the Airmail app I see that I am 1 version behind. If I click the "update" button, all I see is the progress indicator spinning for hours.

I've tried:

- Restarting my Mac
- Clearing App Store cookies
- "Reset Application" in App Store
- Running `killall -KILL storeagent` (which says `No matching processes belonging to you were found`)
- Running Disk Utility to check for any problems (none found)

How can I restore my ability to update apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I had to delete the Airmail app and reinstall it entirely. It's now able to update.

The problem appears to be due to the fact that when Airmail 2 was upgraded to Airmail 3, the internal app version was 3 while the version shown in the Applications folder was v2. I think this confused App Store.